# Stripping out comments from the project files just for the release build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, release, comments

I work on multiple ASP.NET/SharePoint C# projects. During development we use to put elaborate comments for better understanding. But before i want to give a release build i want to hide all the comments (not to remove them). Is there any VS plugin or some tool to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hide from what? Remove from resulting assembly? Release mode removes comments.

Comment: @Michel: afaik, building in release mode removes metadata you don't want to preserve (comemnts) and leaves (generates appropriate file) - you want (xml reference)