# How to stop comments being included in C# release build .exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, dotpeek

To my perhaps naïve surprise, decompiling (using dotPeek) a large .NET 8, C#, WinForms app that I have been working on for many months - every single one of my comments was preserved.

Built in VS 2022, 17.8.0.

"Ah", I said... "it's a debug build, my bad, switch to Release".

To my even greater surprise, all the comments were preserved in a Release build too?

I've found multiple sources on the web, including here on SO that state Release strips out comments, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214784/stripping-out-comments-from-the-project-files-just-for-the-release-build), except - that appears to be very much not the case.

What gives? How to exclude comments from a Release build? I suspect it's me, not you...

Screenshot below, all I've done to generate this is build the Solution in VS, then drag the Release .exe straight into dotPeek, and navigate in the left pane to the file that's shown in VS.

[image]

Comment: What comments exactly are you talking about? XmlDoc? Random comments inside your functions?

Comment: Everything; well formatted Doxygen comments, random inline commends inside methods, development dandruff like "todo: fix this mess" at the end of lines... everything.

Comment: @mountainred Please share a screenshot with us, because (from my perspective) I think you're just looking at your own actual source files that are being linked-in via SourceLink or even older snapshots of them  _raw embedded source files_ rather than the comments being preserved _specifically_. This is a recent-ish change in NuGet and .NET.

Comment: Thanks Dai, a screenshot of what specifically? Configuration of dotPeek, or something else? What I'm looking at in dotPeek certainly looks *exactly* like my source, but all I've dragged into dotPeek is the .exe alone. That's not to say it isn't somehow finding my source files on my machine, because I don't know how to setup dotPeek properly...

Comment: I just want to a see screenshot of your code in VS open side-by-side with the dotPeek window that you say shows your `// inline comments` and/or `/* block comments */` - because that's what you're describing, right? ...or are you only referring to your `/// <summary>XML Comments</summary` ? (XML Comments only appear with member and type signatures, whereas inline and block comments can appear anywhere, especially within methods.

Comment: Yep, both my // inline comments and /* block comments */ are showing, I have no /// XML commentary. One mo, let me work out how to post images on SO...

Comment: Screenshot added, simplest example I could find...

Comment: I don't think that means what you think it means. Try your experiment again on another machine that doesn't have the source code sitting there on the disk, right where it was when you compiled the binary. And remove any .pdb files.

Comment: _all the comments were preserved_: One should ensure that all of one's comments in code are always professional.

Comment: @user246821 I put poop jokes in my comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After installing the current dotPeek and attempting to repro this with a Debug-mode `.dll` of my own, and seeing my own (non-XML) comments repeated *verbatim* I quickly deduced it's just dotPeek's feature to show you the *actual* source-files using the file-paths embedded in the PDBs.

[image]

So, **no**, your built project output assemblies/executables **do not** contain your comments.

Comment: The way to prove this would be to compile your code to an assembly. Then change a comment (without recompiling) and fire up DotPeek. If you look in an assembly (with a primitive tool like `ildasm` you're not going to see any comment information. You can find XML comment information if you configure the compiler to output a compiled xml comment file